# Not sure what this recursive function returns

Tags: c++, recursion

I am reading about recursive functions, and I have been trying to figure out the mathematical formula for this one. I thought maybe it was a logarithmic function, but that does not seem to be it. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

```
unsigned f(unsigned n){
    if(n<2)
    return 1;

    return 1 + f(n/2);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is a logarithm function, just to the base 2. More specifically, it's the <s>`ceil`</s> `1 + floor(log2(n))`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are concerned about the math formula that the function is based on:

Here it is: `f` is a function of `n`:

```
f(n) = 1 + f(n/2) if n >=2
f(n) = 1          if n <=1  //n is unsigned so n >=0
```

With the above formula in mind, the underlying algorithm then have logarithmic complexity. The reason is that at every step, it will reduce the size of `n` by half and it will take `log(n)` (base 2) steps to reach 1, therefore, it is logarithmic complexity with `O(logn)`.

Comment: The function being a logarithm function is quite irrelevant toward it's complexity and vice-versa.

Comment: @MooingDuck I never mentioned that the function is a logarithm function, I meant the algorithm that the function implements has logarithmic complexity.

Comment: @MooingDuck Would you explain more? I don't quite understand why my understanding was wrong, do you mean the algorithm that `f` implements do not have logarithmic complexity? Thanks~

Comment: Oh, the function does indeed have logarithmic complexity.  But read the question again.  Nobody cares what the complexity is.  He wants to know what the function _does_.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said "mathematical function" and that's set the perspective for existing answers, but to show another perspective, it returns:

- number of bits needed to store `n` (if you consider 1 bit necessary to meaningfully encode number 0 distinct from no number at all)
- 1-based index of the most significant bit set in `n|1`, aka
- minimum of (1) and (the 1-based index of the most significant bit set in `n`)

Sometimes when you're looking at code it can help to see that a function could be used with different intent - either perspective might make it easier to understand the context of use.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns the number of times the function executes by dividing the whole number by 2 until reaching zero

EX:

```
f(8)-

return f(4) //continue on
return f(2) //continue on
return f(1) //we know this is 1
return f(2) //now we can do this one, 2
return f(4) //and this one, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

More precisely, this implements floor(logbase2(n))

Comment: Actually, it's the `ceil`. You can check by calculating `log2(3)` = 1.5849... while `f(3)` gives 2.